# How to limit flagging of articles to users with sufficient userpoints using Rules?

Tags: users, rules, flags, userpoints

I am using [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules). Users earn points for publishing and commenting but are deducted points for flagging their articles for announcement on the front page (a kind of a fee). The fee per announcement is say 150 points.

Obviously, if they don't have at least 150 points, they should not be able to flag. So I need a rule that would check if the author has at least 150 points and if not - block the flagging action with an error message: `Sorry, you don't have enough`.

Yet, I just can't figure out how to set up such a rule. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,did you find a solution?If yes could you post it here?thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are the headlines of a possible solution to answer this question:

## Step 1 - Create a designated role

Create a new "role" corresponding to users with (say) 150 points, assume you name the role `UsersWith150Points`.

## Step 2 - Limit access to the flag

Secure the access to the flag to users with role `UsersWith150Points`.

## Step 3 - Create some Rules logic

Any time a user gains points, use a rule to ***check if the user has at least 150 points***. If so, have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module grant access to the `UsersWith150Points` role.

Similarly, if a user looses points, also use a rule to ***check if user no longer has at least 150 points***. If so, have the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module remove access to the `UsersWith150Points` role.

Sounds easy and pretty forward ... except ... there is no (easy) solution to have a Rules Condition to "check the current user points for a user" (unless you're willing to use custom PHP logic in your Rules Condition). However, the clue to make this rule work anyhow, is to use as a very first Rules Action "Load user points of a user". For an example rule, which is close that what you'd need, refer to "[How to create rule to change user role based on points (using User Points module)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53693/how-to-create-rule-to-change-user-role-based-on-points-using-user-points-module/207535#207535)": you'd only have to add a Rules Action to grant or remove some role (and adapt the user points threshold to your '150').