# How to periodically deduct user points for flagged nodes?

Tags: 7, rules, flags, cron, userpoints

I have a node which is published. And I have a global flag, which users have to mark to make nodes visible in [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). This is easy to do.

But then I need to charge 40 user points for every day that node remains flagged. And when user doesn't have enough points anymore, then node must be unflagged.

**Possible realization what I tried:**

**via CRON:** I tried to make a rule for that, but when I add an Event (= *On CRON Run*), then I cannot add an action with user points. Some people say it should be an extra script for cron, but I don't know how to make it.

**via Rules:** I tried to make a rule on Event "*When node is flagged*" and make a Scheduled Rule with the same -40pts for user nextday. It works only once until the Scheduled Rule completed or until cron is running. So I cannot make a loop properly.

I've no more ideas to get it working. Maybe I just lost something while making Rules?

Answer (score 0):

## Part 1 - Deducting user points

#### Repeat the daily deduction of user points

Use the rules scheduler as explained in the video about "[Repeating scheduled events](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/repeating-scheduled-events)". The "clue" here is:

- as the last action of your rule, you reschedule the same rule to be executed again after +1 day(s).
- the very first time you need to trigger the execution of this rule manually (from the Rules UI). Or you can use the Rules Event "when node is flagged".

#### Video tutorials

If you're not familiar (enough/yet) with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), checkout the 32 (!!!) great, and free, video tutorials [Learn the Rules framework](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/learn-the-rules-framework).

## Part 2 - Stop deducting if insufficient user points

The 2nd part of your question is about "*... when user doesn't have enough points anymore, then node must be unflagged ...*". The challenge with that is that there is no Rules Condition like "If user has less then X user points".

However, to also make that work, you can use a Rules Action "Load user points of a user", as an alternative (work around?) for something like a missing Rules Condition to "check the current user points for a user". Have a look at my answer to "[How to create rule to change user role based on points (using User Points module)?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53693/how-to-create-rule-to-change-user-role-based-on-points-using-user-points-module/207535#207535)", which includes an sample rule that uses this Rules Action.

So all you have to do is to further enhance your rule as in Part 1, by using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module so that your Rules Action will look something like so:

> Load user points balance
>
> **If** user points balance > 40
>
> **then** reschedule the same rule to execute in 1 day.